# Unresolved reference: iosSimulatorArm64

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin, kmm

I got a blocker when trying to convert existing simple android app writing in kotlin to [KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html).

Below is the following error.

```
Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'kmmsharedmodule (:kmmsharedmodule)'.
Read more https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#setting-up-targets

Unresolved reference: iosSimulatorArm64
```

I read the documentation provided in the link but seems not a direct solution to what i wanted.

The process i took was just by adding KMM module through provided support in android stuido.

I've looked for others sources but i couldn't find any related problems

Comment: What kotlin plugin version do you use? Same problem popped out in my case after downgrading to `1.5.21`. Looks like `iosSimulatorArm64` target was introduced in version `1.3.30`. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#apple-silicon-support

Comment: Simply removing this target from `build.gradle` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your compose version to `1.0.3` then you can set Kotlin Compiler Version to `1.5.30` . Now `iosSimulatorArm64` will work fine as it was introduced in version 1.5.30